# Possible to change authenticated back to unauthenticated on AWS credential provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I know that we can change the unauthenticated user to authenticated by providing "logins" to the AWSCognitoCredentialProvider. I've implemented the FB login and that works pretty well.

Now the thing is, what if the user wants to log in without FB credential again? Just like the way he used to before linking his FB account to the app. Thus, I need to clear the credential provider associated with his FB credential and give him the unauthenticated role back.

What I have tried is to use the clearing cached credential method but as soon as I initialize a new credential provider without logins, errors occur. The errors are about the refresh failure, openIDGet failure.

Could anyone help on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=167545&tstart=0) you can call the [UnlinkIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_UnlinkIdentity.html) API to unlink a login from an existing identity. It is important to note that this will make the identity inaccessible, not unauthenticated.

If the goal is to "reset" your credentials provider, the mobile SDKs have methods for doing this:

- [clearKeychain](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Authentication/AWSCredentialsProvider.m#L466) in iOS
- [clear](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/src/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java#L279) in Android

These methods will clear any saved identity id and credentials, allowing the user to go back to the unauthenticated state in your app. When they login again, the new identity id will be merged into their existing identity.